# Accept allow contact sync and messaging via command line

Tags: adb, bluetooth, shell, command-line

I would like to know if there is a way to "Allow Contact Sync" and "Allow access to Messages" on Android phone using command line.

When the notification is received on my phone, it prompts me to Allow or Deny. I can accept it using:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN && \
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT && \
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_ENTER
```

Unfortunately, this command doesn't work consistently and sometimes due to timing issues I am unable to allow contact sync.

As this command is device-dependent, is there any better way to allow contact sync and allow messaging on Android phone using command line so it automatically accepts Allow when notification is received on the phone?